# Higher Ranked Trait Bound and boxed closures lifetime issue

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to write a function returning a boxed closure that can work on references to types with any
lifetime. When writing a specific instance, everything works fine. But when writing a generic
version, I run into lifetime problems.

```
struct Parameter<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let closure = generate_closure_gen();
    let string = String::from("Hello World!");
    let parameter = Parameter { s: &string }; // Error: string does not live long enough
    closure(&parameter);
}

// This one works fine
// Desugared version for Box<Fn(&Parameter)>
fn generate_closure() -> Box<for <'a, 'r> Fn(&'r Parameter<'a>)> {
    Box::new(|c: &Parameter| {})
}

// This one gives lifetime errors
fn generate_closure_gen<C>() -> Box<Fn(&C)> {
    Box::new(|c: &C| {})
}
```

I don't see why the closure needs the type parameter to live longer than it (there is no storage or anything ...). And it works for the non-generic version with HRTB, it just feels like it should be possible to make it work with the generic version.
Also, if I try to write the specific version using the generic version, I get a type error

```
// Desugared version for Box<Fn(&Parameter)>
fn generate_closure_2() -> Box<for <'a, 'r> Fn(&'r Parameter<'a>)> {
    generate_closure_gen()
}

src/main.rs:22:5: 22:27 error: mismatched types:
 expected `Box<for<'r, 'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r Parameter<'r>) + 'static>`,
    found `Box<for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r _) + 'static>`
(expected concrete lifetime,
    found bound lifetime parameter ) [E0308]
src/main.rs:22     generate_closure_gen()
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:22:5: 22:27 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

([playpen link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a87c429af45f4d4e646f&version=nightly))

Comment: The compiler does not seem to insert the `for<'a>` by itself when given a generic parameter. If you do not receive any satisfying explanation, you might want to post a link to this question on https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/ where Rust developers are more likely to hang around.

Comment: My answer was obviously wrong, so I deleted it. But your comment is explaining what exactly do you mean:  "I don't see why the closure needs the type parameter to live longer than it (there is no storage or anything ...). And it works for the non-generic version with HRTB, it just feels like it should be possible to make it work with the generic version." – @Vaelden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type parameters have a lifetime bound. That lifetime bound is the shortest of all of the implementor's lifetime parameters. You omitted it on `generate_closure_gen`, so the compiler inferred it, but if we explicitly wrote it out, the function definition would look like this:

```
fn generate_closure_gen<'a, C: 'a>() -> Box<Fn(&C)> {
    Box::new(|c: &C| {})
}
```

Making this change doesn't solve our problem, though.

To understand why, we need to figure out what `C` is inferred to be. You call the closure with a `&'y Parameter<'x>`, and the closure accepts `for<'b> &'b C`, so `C` is `Parameter<'x>`. `Parameter<'x>` has a lifetime parameter, which will have an influence on the lifetime bound on `C`.

Lifetime parameters in generic functions must be substituted with lifetimes that start before the function call. In this case, this means that the lifetime of any `C` we pass to the closure must be valid before the call to `generate_closure_gen`. That's because `C` is bound to a specific lifetime, not to any lifetime; i.e. when `C` is `Parameter<'x>`, the `'x` must be known in advance; we can't have a different `'x` each time we call the closure. In other words, what you'd like to have is something like this:

```
fn generate_closure_gen<C: for<'a> 'a>() -> Box<Fn(&C)> {
    Box::new(|c| {})
}
```

But unfortunately, that isn't legal as of Rust 1.7.